# Android Photo Viewer Demo

Tags: android, photo, viewer

I've been trying to figure out how to display a photo on Android.  I can create an ImageView and display a picture, but the functionality is limited (no zoom, pan or share).  Is there a demo or tutorial with code out there on how to do this?  I've been searching all week with no luck.

Thanks.

P.S.> Please No Snark!

Maybe I don't understand how to create a uri correctly or how to make my resource available to the viewer.  I have a resource ID, R.drawable.opal, I'm using to display different minerals and gems for a science project.  If the student clicks the small sample photo, then I want to bring up a bigger and better viewer for the photo to allow them to compare to their collected rock.

Comment: Try this
http://code.google.com/p/apics/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FEE546-Project3%2Fsrc%2Fandroid%2Fcom%2Fapp
I havent tested it hope it works fine :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at it.  Seems complicated just to display a photo.

Comment: It doesn't look like it does that.  It looks like it shows multiple types of things (geopoints, ...) and only if it is part of the application's data.  My images are resources which need to be given to the Image Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need to build your own you should probably just use the gallery's viewer.  Send it the picture by using the view intent like so:

```
Intent viewImageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(viewImageIntent);
```

Replace "uri" with the image's uri of course. Writing your own viewer is really involved and would include threading, physics calculations and handling touch inputs.

Comment: Something like what you describe is exactly what I'm looking for in a tutorial.  I tried to do exactly what you describe but it crashes.

Comment: What does the log say when it crashes?